# How to let my program accept multiple variables and search the specified directory? Bash Script

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

echo input directory 1
read dir1
dir1a="$dir1"
echo input directory 2
read dir2
dir2a="$dir2"

pathIs="/$dir1/$dir2"
cd $pathIs

echo $pathIs

echo input file name
read file

find . -iname "$file" -print
```

---

The above script works fine so long i know how many directories and subdirectories i am going to search (2 in the above example).

My questions:
1. I would like to modify it to work to any number of subdirectories (example 3 or 4)?
2. Even I use for loop to enter multiple directories, i get the problem how to tell the
pathIs variable, how many directories i have entered?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo directory name
read num

for i in $num

do
echo input directory 1
read dir
done

pathIs="/$dir1/$dir2"
cd $pathIs


echo input file name
read file

find . -iname "$file" -print
```

Comment: I'm probably missing something here. What is it you're trying to achieve? If it is a script which asks for a directory and a filename and then searches for that file in the specified directory (recursively), you could specify the path in a variable instead of asking for all the directories that compose the path (i.e.: the input will already be $pathIs). But please clarify what you need first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options.

1. Ask the user in advance how many entries will be provided, then read that many times
2. Let the user terminate their entries, perhaps by giving an empty entry

To do the second option, you could use a general pattern in most programming languages - a "read ahead, read while" loop.

```
   read x
   while [ $x ]; do
      echo "Do something with $x"
      read x
   done
   echo "DONE"
```

So we read x once. Then we go into a `while` loop, which checks the variable, does something with it, then reads into it again, and keeps going until a terminating condition is encountered.

In the example above, if `[ $x ]` evaluates to false (an empty string), then the loop exits. Instead of `echo "Do something with $x"`, you'll want to append the string to the `pathIs` variable.

One other thing -- most useful shell scripts don't read inputs of that kind from stdin. Eventually you'll want to process parameters given at the command line instead.

Comment: #!/bin/bash;
declare -a Dir;
pathIs="";
echo enter directory;
while read line;
do;
    echo enter directory;
    Dir=("${Dir[@]}" $line);
done;
echo ${Dir[@]};
for i in ${Dir[@]};
do;
    echo the array is ${Dir[$i]};
    #pathIs="$pathIs""${Dir[$i]}";
    pathIs="$pathIs""/""$i";

done;

echo path $pathIs;

cd $pathIs;

echo input file name;
read file;

find . -iname "*$file*" -print;

-----
Thanks for the help and suggestions.
I have done some changes to the script in order to be
generally working. I have adapted what slim suggested to me 
and added some few lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can also read input arguments from the command line like this:

```
for i in {1..$#}
do
   variable[i]=$1
   shift
done
```

The loop goes through all command line arguments, reading them into the "variable" array